# How to check a child value in firebase and hide a button for that user logged in?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I want to hide a `Button` in my app when the user that is logged in has a specified value in the Realtime Firebase Database.

So I have a child where the value changes between Yes or No it depends on what rights the user is having. So I want to hide a `Button` when a user has the value No and when the user has the value Yes, it will be available.

My Firebase database structure is like this: (the child "hasusersstorage" is the Yes or No (Ja/Nei)
[Firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtZrZ.png)

Here is the code I've tried but not managed to get it to work.
The `currentUser` is working, because I use this to setText with a username that is logged in.

```
databaseUsers.child(currentUser).child("hasuserstorage").equalTo("Nei").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("hasuserstorage")) {

                    bttoaddtool.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to hide a Button in my app when the user that is logged in has a specified value in the Firebase database.

If you want to achieve that, then you should create a reference that points exactly to the `hasuserstorage` field.

When you are using the following code query:

```
databaseUsers.child(currentUser).child("hasuserstorage").equalTo("Nei");
```

It doesn't mean that you are checking if the `hasuserstorage` field of the logged-in user holds the value of `Nei`. Assuming that `Ansatte` is a direct child of your root node, to solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference hasUserStorageRef = db.child("Ansatte").child(uid).child("hasuserstorage");
hasUserStorageRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult();
            if(snapshot.exists()) {
                String hasuserstorage = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
                if(hasuserstorage.equals("Ja")) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "hasuserstorage is Ja");
                    bttoaddtool.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if(hasuserstorage.equals("Nei")) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "hasuserstorage is Nei");
                    bttoaddtool.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The above code will hide the button if the `hasuserstorage` will hold the value of `Nei`, otherwise it will display it.

Comment: Hi @Alex Mamo, your'e code looks good. But I can't resolve the `.get` in hasUserStorageRef or `addOnCompleteListener`. Do you have any idea why this is?

Comment: Yes, please update the Firebase dependencies to the latest version and it will work for sure. Right?

Comment: Thank you very much. I thought I had the latest versions, but didn't. So now it works with the latest dependencies versions.

Comment: Good to hear that.